# Android - How to draw 3D cube on a real scene (no marker, camera is open)

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, android-camera

I know I have a basic question, but I can't think how I can draw a **cube** while the **camera** is open. I can **seperately** open the camera or draw a cube in the scene with a background by using **GLSurfaceView.Renderer**, however, I don't know how to combine these two code :s I mean I don't know how to draw the cube when the camera is open.

---

I'm still struggling with this problem..
Here how I'm trying to do it:

in the MainActivity, I'm calling the **camera view** as this:

```
Preview cameraPreview;
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cameraPreview = new Preview(this);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(cameraPreview);
```

and I extend this activity and call the **3D cube** to show up on the **camera view**

However no success,

whenever I include **onPause()**, **onResume()** methods in the second one, the application crashes...

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what called Augmented reality .Take a Framelayout in your xml and add get in in you code by its id . Then add both the SurfaceView and the GlSurfaceView to the FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Other idea:

Steps:
1. Use the [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) class to directly upload the camera stream to an OpenGL ES texture 
2. Render texture to screen using full-screen textured quad (disable depth buffer writing)
3. draw other stuff on top of camera image using openGL 
So what you do: Draw both the camera and the 3d stuff in a GLSurfaceView.